Как в полученном списке результата поиска в Sphinx перенести записи с конкретными id вверх выдачи
Поиск выдает список документов, которые можно отсортировать разными способами. Как сделать так, чтобы документы с определенными id выдавались всегда вверху результатов, не зависимо от сортировок

А какая разница, в каком порядке отдаст сфинкс? всё одно сортировка будет уже на SQL-сервере...

решил созданием группы условий после select-а, примерно так:
SELECT  *, (id in ('7','9','23')) as top FROM users 
ORDER BY top DESC, dt_reg ASC


А почему не сразу ORDER BY (id IN ('7','9','23')) DESC? Тогда в списке вывода оно вообще не надо.

select 
id, col1, col2, col3,...,sort_col1, sort_col2, ...,
case 
 when id in (id_top1, id_top2, ..) then 0
 else rown_number() over (order by sort_col1, sort_col2,...)
end n
from table
order by n


Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].
